# How does facebook detect when a link as been PASTED

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

Facebook's status update input (well, contenteditable div) detects links.

When typing a link it waits until the spacebar is pressed before fetching the URL.

When pasting a link it fetches the URL instantly.

I can already parse the url after the spacebar is pressed...but I'm not sure about detecting when content is pasted.

Any solution would be awesome; a jQuery formatted solution will be BEST!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Modern day browsers support [onpaste](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.onpaste):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>onpaste event example</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Play with this editor!</h1>
<textarea id="editor" rows="3" cols="80">
Try pasting text into this area!
</textarea>

<script>
function log(txt) {
  document.getElementById("log").appendChild(document.createTextNode(txt + "\n"));
}

function pasteIntercept(evt) {
  log("Pasting!");
}

document.getElementById("editor").addEventListener("paste", pasteIntercept, false);
</script>

<h2>Log</h2>
<textarea rows="15" cols="80" id="log" readonly="true"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's so obvious... why is everyone else overcomplicating this in their answers?

Comment: My gosh I feel like an idiot now. msdn says its been there since version 5! Thanks, I'm away from my dev machine but I'll let you know how well it works. Thanks for the obvious!

Comment: however, the onpaste is called before pasting happens. so one would have to set some flag for pasting and than call onchange

Comment: Or just use `setTimeout()` in the callback instead of setting a flag and calling onchange.

Answer (score 3):

Listen to the `keyup` event in the field. If the field's content has changed by more than 1 character after one `keyup`, something has been pasted.

As @epascarello points out, check right click events, too, as the user could be using the context menu.

Comment: duh. makes sense. my brain is fried today. I'll try this in a bit and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: How about right click and paste OR view and paste. key events are only part of the equation.

Comment: Just checking right click isn't good enough, the click on the actual context menu item won't fire the right click event, so you'd be firing too early.

Comment: Also, what about the these keys in this order `alt->E->P`?

Comment: onpaste event works perfectly. This method would requires a key being pressed before working. Thanks for the tip, though.

Comment: Didn't know about onpaste - good to know. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I could paste just one character.

Answer (score 2):

Compare successive onChange events. If the difference between them is more than one character, it's a paste. Else it's typed in.

Comment: The onChange event only fires after a `blur` of the textarea, so this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I am actually going to suggest it listens to every `keyup` because it has multiple uses, if you type `@` it will suggest friends, etc.

It probably scans the text and finds links and makes them, well linkable, and then crawls the page so you can post it as "Sharing" the page.

Comment: Didn't know about the @ sign. +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#text").keypress (function(e){
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if ((code == 86 || code == 118) && e.ctrlKey) //86 = v 118 = V
    {
     alert("Pasted!");
    }   
   });
  });
 </script>

</head>
<body>
 <textarea id="text">
 </textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most reliable way to do this is to implement it on your own, for example like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ctrl = false;
  var pasted = 0;
  $("#paste").keydown(function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        $("#console").val($("#console").val()+String(code)+",");
    if (!ctrl && code == 17){
        ctrl = true;
    }else{
        if(ctrl && code == 86){
        $(".paste>div")[0].innerHTML = "Pasted "+(++pasted)+"x";
      }
    }
  });
  $("#paste").keyup(function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 17){
        ctrl = false;
    }
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var ctrl = false;
  var pasted = 0;
  $("#paste").keydown(function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  $("#console").val($("#console").val()+String(code)+",");
    if (!ctrl && code == 17){
     ctrl = true;
    }else{
     if(ctrl && code == 86){
       $(".paste>div")[0].innerHTML = "Pasted "+(++pasted)+"x";
      }
    }
  });
  $("#paste").keyup(function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 17){
     ctrl = false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div.top {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.top>div {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  resize: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
  <div>
    <div>
      Try paste here:
    </div>
    <div class="test">
      <textarea value="" id="paste"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      Console:
    </div>
    <div class="console">
      <textarea value="" id="console"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="paste">
    <div>
      Pasted:
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Check the field at half-second increments. If you detect a large change in the amount of text, it has probably been pasted.

Answer (score -3):

keypress does not work in IE8. Use keydown instead.

Comment: $('#textAreaID')
.live('keydown', function (e) {

    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if ((code == 86 || code == 118) && e.ctrlKey) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
});