# copy - paste in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
<input name="mpan[]" value="" maxlength="2" size="2">
<input name="mpan[]" value="" maxlength="2" size="3"> 
<input name="mpan[]" value="" maxlength="2" size="3">
<input name="mpan[]" value="" maxlength="2" size="12">
```

What I have to do is I am provided with a large key for example `0380112129021`. When I do Ctrl+C on that key and select any box and press Ctrl+V, the number automatically get pasted in different box, for example: first input box gets `03`, next gets `801`, next gets `112` and rest gets pasted on last one `129021`.how do i achive this from javascript

Comment: @rlb.usa: How to achieve this in JS, I suppose.

Comment: Does it need to be Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V?

Comment: Btw: your `maxlength` doesn't comply with required input lengths. You now have 4 input elements where you can input max 2 characters. Maybe you want to swap it with the `size` or align the values to be the same?

Comment: Retrieving the pasted text requires browser-specific code; I don't know off-hand of any framework that normalizes that, but I'd like to :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to catch paste events (rather than the literal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>), the `onpaste` event may be for you, and is supported by most browsers according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891145/how-does-facebook-detect-when-a-link-as-been-pasted).

The splitting of the input value you could do using [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Substring).

Comment: He's also going to have to get the data from the paste - in other words, the clipboard contents. That doesn't seem to be standardized across browsers, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. On each of the input box, add an onkeyup handler and inspect the input values.

Little clarification, you're trying to do something like serial/key input boxes, right?

Comment: By using onmouseup? s/he can use the same function for the different events.

Comment: There's also pasting from the Edit menu to consider, or by dragging.

Comment: In that case there's onchange. Or you could (in extreme cases) run a timer.
For the dragging case, I'm sure onmouseup captures it.

Answer (score 0):

okay if you have no idea you should read through some stuff.

i can recommend to read about

- javascript - events.
- especialy the onkeyup/onkeydown events
- stringparsing (substring)

after that you will see the answer glowing on your screen ;-)

a little hint: if you store the pressed keys to a variable, it should be cleared after the action is triggered. and you should check what you have in you keypress cache and clear illigal input.