# Detect pasted text with Ctrl+v or right click -> paste

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript how do you to detect what text the user pastes into a textarea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does facebook detect when a link as been PASTED](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891145/how-does-facebook-detect-when-a-link-as-been-pasted)

Comment: Nope,for example I paste "test textarea" , I want to detect what text is pasted , in this case - "test textarea"

Comment: you probably can't do that cross-browser...

Comment: I want to know what's the length of the pasted text.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use the paste event to detect the paste in most browsers (notably not Firefox 2 though). When you handle the paste event, record the current selection, and then set a brief timer that calls a function after the paste has completed. This function can then compare lengths and to know where to look for the pasted content. Something like the following. For the sake of brevity, the function that gets the textarea selection does not work in IE. See here for something that does: [How to get the start and end points of selection in text area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053542/how-to-get-the-start-and-end-points-of-selection-in-text-area/3053640#3053640)

```
function getTextAreaSelection(textarea) {
    var start = textarea.selectionStart, end = textarea.selectionEnd;
    return {
        start: start,
        end: end,
        length: end - start,
        text: textarea.value.slice(start, end)
    };
}

function detectPaste(textarea, callback) {
    textarea.onpaste = function() {
        var sel = getTextAreaSelection(textarea);
        var initialLength = textarea.value.length;
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            var val = textarea.value;
            var pastedTextLength = val.length - (initialLength - sel.length);
            var end = sel.start + pastedTextLength;
            callback({
                start: sel.start,
                end: end,
                length: pastedTextLength,
                text: val.slice(sel.start, end)
            });
        }, 1);
    };
}

var textarea = document.getElementById("your_textarea");
detectPaste(textarea, function(pasteInfo) {
    alert(pasteInfo.text);
    // pasteInfo also has properties for the start and end character
    // index and length of the pasted text
});
```

Comment: Does this poll every 1 millisecond?

Comment: @chug2k: No, it only runs that function after 1 millisecond (or whatever the browser implements instead) once after every paste.

Comment: Just for some additional info for anyone else curious- the reason for the setTimeout() is that the onpaste event happens *before* the input/textarea is updated. (I think the event is intended to let other applications decide how to handle the paste, for example if user pastes a file or image or whatever). So if you try to read the value of the input/textarea in the onpaste handler, it still has the old text in it.

Answer (score 19):

**HTML5** already provides `onpaste` not only `<input/>` , but also editable elements (`<p contenteditable="true" />`, ...)

```
<input type="text" onpaste="myFunction()" value="Paste something in here">
```

[More info here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onpaste.asp)

Comment: Be careful, this is not a Web standard. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/onpaste. (also, MDN is much more reliable than W3Schools for Web APIs)

Comment: It's part of the W3 Working Draft: https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#clipboard-event-paste

Comment: One thing to note is that this event fires *before* the input/textarea is updated. So if your handler tries to get the value of the input/textarea in the event handler, it's not going to have the pasted value. This is why the accepted answer is essentially equivalent to `onpaste="setTimeout(myFunction)"`

Answer (score 4):

Quite an old thread, but you might now use https://willemmulder.github.io/FilteredPaste.js/ instead. It will let you control what gets pasted into a textarea or contenteditable.

Comment: Link down. Is/was this better than `onpaste`?

Comment: @qräbnö Updated the link; thanks. It's a very old project  though, so you'll have to figure out yourself whether it's still more useful than simple onpaste... Sorry!

Comment: I like it. I use it maybe. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Works on IE 8 - 10

Creating custom code to enable the Paste command requires several steps.

1. Set the event object returnValue to false in the onbeforepaste event to enable the Paste shortcut menu item.
2. Cancel the default behavior of the client by setting the event object returnValue to false in the onpaste event handler. This applies only to objects, such as the text box, that have a default behavior defined for them.
3. Specify a data format in which to paste the selection through the getData method of the clipboardData object.
4. invoke the method in the onpaste event to execute custom paste code.

To invoke this event, do one of the following:

- Right-click to display the shortcut menu and select Paste.
- Or press CTRL+V.

**Examples**

```
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT>
var sNewString = "new content associated with this object";
var sSave = "";
// Selects the text that is to be cut.
function fnLoad() {
    var r = document.body.createTextRange();
    r.findText(oSource.innerText);
    r.select();
}
// Stores the text of the SPAN in a variable that is set 
// to an empty string in the variable declaration above.
function fnBeforeCut() {
    sSave = oSource.innerText;
    event.returnValue = false;
}
// Associates the variable sNewString with the text being cut.
function fnCut() {
    window.clipboardData.setData("Text", sNewString);
}
function fnBeforePaste() {
    event.returnValue = false;
}
// The second parameter set in getData causes sNewString 
// to be pasted into the text input. Passing no second
// parameter causes the SPAN text to be pasted instead.
function fnPaste() {
    event.returnValue = false;
    oTarget.value = window.clipboardData.getData("Text", sNewString);
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY onload="fnLoad()">
<SPAN ID="oSource" 
      onbeforecut="fnBeforeCut()" 
      oncut="fnCut()">Cut this Text</SPAN>
<INPUT ID="oTarget" TYPE="text" VALUE="Paste the Text Here"
      onbeforepaste="fnBeforePaste()" 
      onpaste="fnPaste()">
</BODY>
```

Full doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536955(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I like the suggestion for the right click

```
$("#message").on('keyup contextmenu input', function(event) { 
  alert("ok");
});
```

finded here:

Source:
[Fire event with right mouse click and Paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28062447/fire-event-with-right-mouse-click-and-paste)

Answer (score 0):

Following may help you

```
  function submitenter(myfield,e)
  {
    var keycode;
    if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
    else if (e) keycode = e.which;
    else return true;
    if (keycode == //event code of ctrl-v)
    {
      //some code here
    }

  }

  <teaxtarea name="area[name]" onKeyPress=>"return submitenter(this,event);"></textarea>
```

Comment: Yes ,but what will be on the place of "some code here" ,if I want to detect what text the user pastes?

Answer (score 0):

The input event fires when the value of an , , or  element has been changed.

```
const element = document.getElementById("input_element_id");
element.addEventListener('input', e => {
// insertText or insertFromPaste
   if(inputType === "insertFromPaste"){
       console.log("This text is copied");
   }
   if(inputType === "insertText"){
       console.log("This text is typed");
   }


})
```

Comment: this is quite incomplete, what is inputType suposed to be? it should be `e.inputType`

Comment: and if you're using React events, (`onInput`) you might need to use `e.nativeEvent.inputType`

Answer (score -1):

You could either use html5 `oninput` attribute or jquery `input` event

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $("body").on('input','#myinp',function(){
 $("span").css("display", "inline").fadeOut(2000);
  });
</script>
<style>
span {
  display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<input id="myinp" type="search" onclick="this.select()" autocomplete="off" placeholder="paste here">

<span>Nice to meet you!</span>

</body>
</html>
```