# Is there an event that occurs after paste?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect pasted text with ctrl+v or right click -> paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211505/detect-pasted-text-with-ctrlv-or-right-click-paste)

I'm coding a js editor now.
I want to do something (detect pasted text, etc.) just after the paste.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of handling paste event:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/tests/cutcopypaste.html

It's supported on many browsers but not 100% - see this table for compatibility: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/cutcopypaste.html

You can also work around not having a paste event on some browsers by:

- Remembering full contents of the form field at some time
- Setting a timeout event
- On timeout, take the contents of the field again, compare to the previous contents, and detect changes. Lather, rinse, repeat

Comment: It is possible to "paste" the exact same text into a field, and to still want to do something special if the user tries that

Comment: @Joel - OK, I give up. What would be the purpose of doing something like that? Short of "You pasted unchanged text" warning, I can't come up with anything useful.

Comment: Maybe you transform the text after pasting, and so it won't stay the same? It doesn't matter why - it could happen.  Anyway, I upvoted the answer, I just wanted to make sure anyone later on was aware of the caveat.