# Detect paste in input box

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript

I have a input box, and I would like to use vbscript or javascript (no jquery) to capture the paste event.

Comment: Check answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211505/detect-pasted-text-with-ctrlv-or-right-click-paste/68277966#68277966

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use the onpaste event to capture the event and do what you need in Javascript. E.g. to disable the paste in an input text field:

```
<input type="text" onpaste="return false;" />
```

Answer (score 9):

Javascript supports onpaste:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/cutcopypaste.html

Comment: Mozilla says this isn't on any standards track: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/onpaste

Answer (score 6):

Just for future readers finding this as I did.

You will still be able to drop text into an input with the onpaste="return false;" attribute. If you want to avoid this, you can do something like this:

```
var input_element = document.getElementById("Element");
input_element.addEventListener("drop", function (event) {
    var types = event.dataTransfer.types;
    
    if (types.length > 2 || types.indexOf("text/plain") === -1)
        event.preventDefault();
    else {
      setTimeout(function () { input_element.value = ""; }, 10);
    }
}, false);
```