# HERE API Autocomplete - Paste an address isn't found. Only typing

Tags: autocomplete, geocoding, here-api, here-autocomplete

I'm using the autocomplete API of HERE API.
When I paste some address: "4141 Pingree Rd, Howell, MI 48843, United States", it finds nothing.
But, if I'm typing that address, it is found.

Why if I paste an address it can't find anything? only by typing?

Here's the https request (without the app_code & app_id):
https://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?maxresults=5&country=USA&language=en-US&jsonattributes=1&query=4141%20Pingree%20Rd%2C%20Howell%2C%20MI%C2%A048843%2C%20United%20States&beginHighlight=%3Cmark%3E&endHighlight=%3C%2Fmark%3E&jsoncallback=__jsonp1_

Thanks.

Comment: Please add the HTTP request that is sent when the user paste an address.

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos - added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is hard to see as it comes from a non-breaking space character (%C2%A0) added between the state 2-letter alpha code (MI in the example) and the postal code (48843).

With a regular space you would see the state code MI followed by **%20** instead of **%C2%A0**.

With the non-breaking space, the API does not find the address. However it finds it with a regular space. Therefore, you need to do some additional string cleanup before sending it to the API, for example by chaining `.replace(/\s/g, ' ')` on the copied string.

Comment: WOW! Thanks. It is really resolved that.

Comment: Welcome. I think that's an edge case the API should handle, however additional user input cleanup client-side does not harm.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use a workaround by detecting the paste in JavaScript and then trigger a "keydown" event on the input to make it bring up the results.

Some ideas:

[Detect paste in input box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450449/detect-paste-in-input-box)

[Trigger a keypress/keydown/keyup event in JS/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368578/trigger-a-keypress-keydown-keyup-event-in-js-jquery)

Comment: The paste is triggering the request, but nothing is returned. Only by typing that address