# Call a JavaScript function when text is paste occurs in a text area

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I would like the text area to call a function when a text is pasted into the text area via mouse clicks. I am not getting it to work the way I wanted using `onChange`.

I am aiming to build something like the Twitter tweet box.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect pasted text with ctrl+v or right click -> paste](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211505/detect-pasted-text-with-ctrlv-or-right-click-paste)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `onPaste` event. As far as I've tested it works for Ctrl+V pasting, and right-click>Paste pasting.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById(<id>).onpaste= function()
{
 //do something
}
```