# Limit textarea based on number of lines?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

When my textarea is filled with content I don't want it to accept anymore content that exceeds its `rows` and `cols`.

Illustration:

Textarea default(part 1):

[image]

Textarea Full(part 2):

[image]

Textarea exceeds height(part 3):

[image]
[image]

I don't want `part 3` to happen, it keeps the height but the content moves when a newline is entered. I have tried the answer from [Limit number of lines in textarea and Display line count using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501043/specify-and-limit-number-of-lines-in-textarea-and-display-line-count-using-jquer) but it only stop my inputs when I press `Enter`, but it keep accepting inputs when enter a long word:

Example: `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`

I tried another way by using `AutoGrow textarea Plugin` because it gets the `Line and Characters per Line`, so when the text line is equal to the `row` of the textarea it will increase its `rows`. It was the closest solution that I can think of but it failed too.

Comment: if you only need to detect pasting text, read http://stackoverflow.com/a/3212056/643500