# Unable to detect pasted text in ASP.Net textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm currently making a TestForm but I've run into some issues.
I have 2 textboxes as follows:

```
<asp:textbox id="VATNbrUser" 
                style="Z-INDEX: 160; POSITION: relative; width: 319px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" runat="server" 
                MaxLength="35" ToolTip="Max. 35 posities" >
<asp:textbox id="AliasUser" 
                style="Z-INDEX: 160; POSITION: relative; width: 319px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" runat="server" 
                MaxLength="35" ToolTip="Max. 35 posities" >
```

Right now, if i want to enable a button if both textboxes are **not** empty. So I made a function:

```
    function ControleInput() {

        document.getElementById('WriteData').disabled = true;
        var allFields = true;

        //Controleren op de aanwezigheid van een alias
        if (!document.getElementById('AliasUser').value.length > 0) {
            allFields = false;
        }

        //Controleren op de aanwezigheid van een BTW-Nummer
        if (!document.getElementById('VATNbrUser').value.length > 0)
        { allFields = false; }
        //Controleren op de aanwezigheid van een afkorting

        if (allFields) {
            document.getElementById('<%=WriteData.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
        }
```

}

which i assign to my textboxes using the following code:

```
    VATNbrUser.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "ControleInput()")
    AliasUser.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "ControleInput()")
```

This code works when the user types data into a Textbox. Yet it doesn't work when the user presses **CTRL+V** or **Right-Click followed by Paste**. What am i doing wrong?

I've tried the following links but to no avail:

[detect pasted text with CTRL+V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211505/detect-pasted-text-with-ctrlv-or-right-click-paste)

[detect CTRL+V using JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903991/how-to-detect-ctrlv-ctrlc-using-javascript)

[ASP.NET Event: Ontextchanged](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.be/2009/03/how-to-use-ontextchanged-event-in.html)

[ASP.NET: TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742880%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: It should be a cross-browser solution. IE is the company standard but Chrome & FF are being more and more used.