# Facebook-like textbox that fetches a URL's contents upon paste

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi all i stuck at a point in which i want to ma a multiple line text box to work just like a FACEBOOK  text box  . i.e. when a URL is pasted or typed (along with the text) it will it fetches the information from the page specifed by URL

well i found somthing at 
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891145/how-does-facebook-detect-when-a-link-as-been-pasted)
i want to know how to get URL in VAR in javascript

`coz when i enter a url it fetches complete information how ever when i put another url it treat it as a text`

Comment: Accept some previous answers and people will be more inclined to help you. 14% needs to go up!

Answer (score 3):

Constantly search the text for a url via regex, possibly on a javascript event like onkeyup.  Use ajax to load the page, and scrape out whatever info you want to display.

http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/evhan_onkeyup.html

http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=URL